# Why does this facebook create album code create duplicate albums?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have this code that works fine (in that it creates the album properly). However, it creates two identical albums. I've tried removing message and privacy (not that this should have changed anything, but still). Nothing I try is changing the fact that this code creates two albums. I've even gone so far as to comment it out to ensure that it was the only code firing and no albums were created. I have code after this to post two test pictures and it only posts the pictures to one of the groups. However, I have an exit after this code, so I've ensured it's the only code firing.

Help, Please!

```
print "Creating album\n";
try {
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', array(
        'access_code' => $access_code,
        'name' => 'Coolest Album',
        'message' => 'Coolest Album containing bike stuff',
        'privacy' => array('value'=>'EVERYONE'),
        ));
} catch (Exception $e) {
print_r($e->getMessage());
}
print "Album created\n";`
```

Comment: Have you tried running the call in the Graph Explorer ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ )? If it create double albums there too please file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Just one totally random thought that may do the double posting. It is not so that this is running on like index.php and you have everything rewritten to index.php? Because then my guess is that the double writing happens because the web browser will try to load the favicon on the page and that get rewritten to also run index.php which creates the album

Comment: I just tried it in Graph Explorer and it works fine. It creates only one album. It appears to be something with the facebook php sdk itself. Who maintains that?

Comment: We do. You can report issues at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4 but my guess is that something is wrong with your code

Comment: Re: index.php. I actually am running it from the command line. I have a series of scripts that I've been using for researching post formats that I run from the command line. They use the same includes, etc, as my prototype that runs via web.

Comment: Here's the full script... The include loads a library that loads the facebook sdk and initializes it. I've used it in numerous other scripts and have it in beta code that works fine for the entire site when posting, commenting, getting groups, etc. The only time I've had an issue like this is with creating the album.

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/x72Y1qbf)

Comment: I just updated the pastebin with the full code (includes the two posts of the pictures to the album). When I run this, it creates two albums and posts (when the exit is taken out) two files to one album. If the entire script were being run twice, I would expect two albums, each with two files in them.  As well, I surrounded the album create with print statements to ensure my sanity was not going, and I only get one set of printed comments.  It's the single call to create the album that's causing two albums.

Comment: Just an update... I experienced this with v3 of the facebook php sdk. I've submitted a bug report with Facebook and they sent it to their second tier support. I haven't heard back since then. I wasn't able to replicate with v4 of the sdk, however in my github bug report (not realizing I was reporting to v4 on v3 code) someone said they were experiencing this in v4 as well. I don't have their specifics though.  This issue was confirmed to be with the access_code generated.

Comment: @iolympian, I just posted on your issue 24297686 before reading this thread. As I mentioned there, I am using the javascript SDK (with Meteor which I initially thought might have been doing double-posting), but I am getting the same duplicate album issue when using the Graph Explorer tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with the SDK but with Facebook itself. I had created a bug report after doing some more tests. Facebook confirmed and fixed the bug. Basically, it had to do with inappropriate permissions handling.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1435856773345641/

Comment: Update, facebook notified me they fixed the bug.

Answer (score 0):

What version of php are using? And, what is the version of the Facebook API? If you use Facebook 2.0, you need php 5.4 or 5.5.
Maybe that could help?

Comment: Per, it was an issue with their old API. Facebook fixed the bug.