# Facebook graph command creating duplicate album

Tags: php, facebook, perl, facebook-graph-api

I've been using the Facebook php sdk to interact with facebook quite successfully. When I tried to create a photo album the code created a duplicate. At first I thought it was the php sdk (using 3.x). I tried switching to Perl with LWP::UserAgent and LWP::Simple::Post to use the http url for graph. Nothing is working. Every way I try I get double albums when I call the code. I've ensured that the code is being called once (mainly because I've created a super small test script to do it and have made outputs to ensure on the command line that it's only calling once.

Here's the url I'm using:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=<access_token>&name=Test+Album+2&message=Test+Description

I've taken off the privacy setting from the url and it hasn't changed the behavior. If I run this directly in the graph explorer, it creates only one album. But any other method (yes, I am using POST and not GET and yes I've tried to pass all the params as post data individually rather than via querystring, either way results in duplicate albums) causes duplicate albums.

Has anyone experienced this? How do I fix it??? I'm at my wits end trying to figure this out.

I've tried it on multiple servers in thoughts that perhaps one of them was using a proxy causing the duplicate call, but whether I run it on my hosting service or on my localhost, I still get duplicates.

No matter what I've tried, if I am creating the album via code in PHP or Perl I get double albums created. HELP!

Comment: And I think I know what is going on. Going to confirm my suspicions and then report the bug to facebook. (Yes, my suspicions are that it's on their side). If I'm correct, I'll post my solution here as well.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue - but using the Javascript SDK. Interestingly, when I use the Graph Explorer tool, I get a two albums created. So that would tend to indicate a bug at the facebook end right? Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I can't seem to mark this as a duplicate issue of the other. So I'll just reference it (even though I see you found the other post).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006673/why-does-this-facebook-album-create-code-create-duplicate-albums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first answer was deleted for some reason so I'm not sure what to do at this point. This question can't be answered because:

> The issue was not with the SDK but with Facebook itself. I had created a bug report after doing some more tests. Facebook confirmed and fixed the bug. Basically, it had to do with inappropriate permissions handling.
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1435856773345641/

There was a bug in Facebook's handling in this instance. I'm hoping this answer doesn't get deleted because someone else may experience this and want to know that it was a bug in Facebook code, not in the PHP SDK or in the user code.

Not sure why Andrew Barber would delete that answer.

Unless someone has a better answer than what Facebook gave to me via bug report follow-up.